# Installing R on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, repository, r

I'm trying to install R on my Ubuntu 22.10, by following [this article](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)
However, when installing the repository, and then updating, I receive the message.

```
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu kinetic-cran40/ Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this "impasse"?
Best regards!

Comment: Have you seen the list of supported releases? Don't think 22.10 is among them yet. You can try installing from the repositories, r-base 4.2.1-3 is in universe.

Comment: "Do you have an idea on how to solve this "impasse"? " contact the maintainer to add suport for 22.10? or use "jammy".

Comment: Thanks!!! It does.

Answer (score 1):

`R`has always been included in the standard software sources of Ubuntu. It can conveniently and safely be installed with

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

Plenty of additional packages also can be installed using `apt`.

You can see them all with the command

```
apt search r-cran
```

or search a specific package like so:

```
~$ apt search r-cran | grep xtable

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

r-cran-xtable/jammy,jammy 1:1.8-4-2 all
~$
```

As a general rule, always check first whether the software you are looking for is available in the standard ubuntu repositories. That is software that is specifically compiled for your Ubuntu version, easy to install, and security updates are automatically applied.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html, the only supported releases are currently:

```
Jammy Jellyfish (22.04, amd64 only)
Impish Indri (21.10, amd64 only),
Focal Fossa (20.04; LTS and amd64 only),
Bionic Beaver (18.04; LTS), and
Xenial Xerus (16.04; LTS).
```

Your release (22.10) is not in this list.
Also in my case, using linux mint 21.10 (vera), the automatic ppa settings fail.

This is due to the use of `lsb_release -cs` in the official [ppa install command](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) to determine your linux flavor:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
```

On my system, `lsb_release -cs` returns `vera`, which is not on the list of supported packages.

#### How to fix

You can try to use the supported release which is closest to your actual release. So for me, this is `jammy` instead of `vera`.

Easiest for me via the graphical Package Source Manager of my system.
The R-Project repo is listed under "additional sources". Edit the ppa repo address to end with `<your desired officially supported release>-cran40/`, e.g.

```
……/ubuntu jammy-cran40/
```

(before, it was:
`vera-cran40/`
or in your case `kinetic-cran40/`
which obviously can not work if you look at the list of supported releases)